# Where should I use CSS vendor prefixes

Tags: css

My question is about CSS vendor prefixes: -webkit, -moz, -ms, -o, etc.

How do I know which I should add to which css properties?

Comment: has been asked before, did you even search ?

Comment: --> http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What CSS3 features still need vendor prefixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445951/what-css3-features-still-need-vendor-prefixes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search through [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/) to see which browser/version combinations need a vendor prefix.

But if you use a build tool, such as [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com), for your front end development work you can have these vendor prefixes automatically added to the resulting CSS. Take a look at [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) ([Grunt plugin](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss) [Gulp plugin](https://github.com/w0rm/gulp-postcss))