# where to check do I really need browser-specific css code?

Tags: css

for example - `column-count`

On [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp) you can see that you need browser specific code:

```
-webkit-column-count:
-moz-column-count:
column-count: 3;
```

The same info is on many other sites, for example - [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/) - for `columns`

In my code I write just this:

```
column-count: 3; or columns: 3;
```

it works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari.

So is there any valid address on the web, where I can see 100% valid info do I need a browser specific css code or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What CSS3 features still need vendor prefixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445951/what-css3-features-still-need-vendor-prefixes). According to [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=column-count) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count#Browser_compatibility) vendor prefixes for `column-count` are only required if you target fairly outdated browsers nobody cares about any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget using W3 schools, its absolutely horrible (see [here](https://www.w3fools.com/));

Check for vendor prefixes here: https://caniuse.com/

An even better answer however, is to let someone else deal with all that for you. For example, this is an excellent library which takes your CSS as input and transforms it to have the proper prefixes according to the filter you specify (generally expressed as `n versions` or as a percent, like `92% coverage`): https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

The filter list can be found here: https://browserl.ist/?q=last%204%20version

You can add that into your build process and its 100% automatic, hands off.

If you're doing a one-off project or website without a build process, you can convert your CSS here https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: on `caniuse.com` I think those are info about using a css property at all. Can't see the info about prefixes, are they required or not.